# Sound disappears in I²S

Tags: audio, i2c, osmc, audio-playback, 1080p

I have a Raspberry Pi B+ version (single core). The ARM frequency is overclocked to 950 MHz

I also have an [IQaudIO I²S DAC HAT](http://www.iqaudio.com/downloads/IQaudIO.pdf) mounted. Sometimes, while playing 1080p with 5.1 sound, the video and sound stutters, and the sound disappears for a few seconds till the video keeps stuttering.

After the stuttering smooths out, the sound comes back on after a few seconds of the smoothing out. I've installed OSMC as the OS.

Comment: This is usually a case of the network not keeping up or the CPU not keeping up.